# Firefox fullpage.js error

Tags: jquery, firefox, height, fullpage.js

I've been having trouble with fullpage.js not fitting to 100% height on firefox. Instead it seems to combine both sections into about 50% worth of the initial screen height

It works on all both chrome and safari but not firefox. However as soon as i resize the browser it returns to it's correct layout. That probably means there's something wrong with how the script is first initialised I'm guessing but despite searching/trying solutions I've come up blank.

It would be amazing if someone would be able to point me in the right direction or even solve this since I'm so stuck.

I've temporarily hosted the file here on a google drive:
[fullpagefail link](http://www.googledrive.com/host/0B33oB8-xYEjDUm9hZ3ZvTDNuMlE)

Thanks!!

Max

Comment: Are you talking about firefox in mobile phone? Because it works as expected in [the demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) in firefox desktop.

Comment: I'm not I'm afraid. I have firefox 35.0.1 desktop and it doesn't seem to be working on that..

Comment: You can try it in browserstack.com or in any other computer. The demo page works in all modern browsers including Firefox 35.0.1

Answer (score 6):

just add doctype tag

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

...